# Difference between 見忘れる and 忘れる

Tags: transitivity

I was speaking with a friend of mine and said I learnt Japanese using some dictionaries and websites. But I forgot to mention that I also use grammar books, so I said:

```
忘れてた！日本語の文法書たくさんよんでいますね。
I forgot! I read many Japanese grammar books.
```

She then corrected me saying it should be 見忘れました instead, hinting that with 忘れてた (or 忘れました） you can't drop what was forgotten (i.e. it needs to be explicitly said e.g.

```
〜を忘れてた
I forgot .
```

Does the 見 at the start of the verb make the transitive verb (requiring an object) into an intransitive verb (not requiring an object)?

The dictionary definitions I have don't show much difference:

> 見忘れる【みわすれる】 v1,vt +
> (1) to forget/to fail to recognize/to fail to recognise/EntL1641770X
>
> 忘れる【わすれる】 v1,vt Pop +
> (1) to forget/to leave carelessly/to be forgetful of/to forget about/to forget (an article)

Possibly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/15118/10888

EDIT: Full conversation below (please ignore spelling mistake of 見忘れました as みわせれりました

[image: Conversation screen grab part a]
[image: Conversation screen grab part b]

Comment: 忘れてた！ sounds fine to me in that context. You could say 言い忘れてた! ("I forgot to say") too, but 見忘れました ("I forgot to see") wouldn't make sense there. Is your friend a native Japanese speaker?

Comment: @chocolate: Yes, they are a native speaker.

Comment: Hmm I don't see why they corrected you to say 見忘れた... Maybe you should ask them *what* they thought you forgot to see...

Comment: Her response:
"忘れました" → 何を忘れたかわからない。so
"見忘れました" → -thumbs up-
Also:
" I forgot " = 忘れてた→ what?
" I forgot ~" = ~を忘れてた

Comment: Seems to me that there are already some misunderstandings before the sentences. Did you put translation together with every your line? (It was chat, right?)

Comment: Yes it was in chat. I'll take this to chat room until we get some more concensus :)

Comment: @chocolate:  それを回答にしたらね。

Comment: み = look.
That looks like this. 
"I forrgotle to look.." 
"What? You say 'I forgot to look'?" 
"No. I want to say 'I forgot'. Why did you think so?"

Comment: I've used 言い忘れた countless times in my life but not sure if I've *ever* used 見忘れた before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason they corrected you to say 見忘れました was that you typed みわせれりました which looked/sounded like みわすれました; as I said in the comment, 見忘れました(I forgot to see) wouldn't make sense there.

And they said 「忘れました→何を忘れたかわからない。見忘れました→」(by which I think they meant to say: "If you just said 忘れました, I wouldn't know what you forgot. So I recommend you say 見忘れました"), and 「忘れてた→what? "I forgot~~" = ～を忘れてた」(by which I think they meant: "If you just said 忘れてた, I'd want to ask 'What did you forget?' so I recommend you say like XXを忘れてた(I forgot + [an object])")...

But, in real life, we often use the phrase 「あっ、忘れた！/ 忘れました！/ 忘れちゃった！etc.」(I forgot!)  or 「あっ、忘れてた！/ 忘れてました！」(I had forgotten! / Now I remembered!) without explicitly mentioning *what* you forgot or forgot to do, so...

After reading your whole conversation, I think you could have said:

> - 忘れました！ / 忘れてました！ 日本語の文法書**も**たくさん読んでいますよ。
>     (Lit: I forgot! / I had forgotten! I read a lot of Japanese grammar books, too.)
> - 言い忘れました！ / 言い忘れてました！ 日本語の文法書**も**たくさん読んでいますよ。
>     (Lit: I forgot to say! / I had forgotten to say! I read a lot of Japanese grammar books, too.)

etc. in your situation.